# Convex Set Examples.

Tags: convex-analysis

Is a closed interval $[a,b]$, or $[0,1]$ in particular, a convex set ?
I mean, let $\lambda\in [0,1]$. Then,
\begin{align}
 a\lambda+(1-\lambda)b&=a\lambda+b -b\lambda  
                      &=(a-b)\lambda+b
\end{align}
Where does it lie?

Comment: Yes, trivially. Segments in the real numbers are just intervals.

Comment: A set in the real line is convex **iff** it is a (possibly extended, or trivial) interval. $(-\infty, 0], (0,1]$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $a \le x \le b$ and $a \le y \le b$,

since $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ are nonnegative,

$\lambda a \le \lambda x \le \lambda b$ and $(1-\lambda )a \le (1-\lambda)y \le (1-\lambda)b$,

Summing the equations, we have

$$a \le \lambda x + (1-\lambda )y \le b$$